# How to open mobile app after clicking a button in mobile browser (using javascript / react) [Deep Linking]

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, deep-linking

So basically what I want is when the user clicks on a button on a mobile browser :

1. If the app is already installed on the user's mobile, the app opens up.
2. If the app is not installed, I want to redirect the user to the play store app/apple store from where the user can install that app.

Any solution/overview/idea/source would be highly appreciated.

**NOTE: I want to do it using JavaScript or React and not java**

***Big THANKS for the help in advance !!***

Answer (score 2):

I found the javaScript solution for this and it is working for Instagram App.

**But the issue I am facing is the "intent URL" present here for Instagram, I found it online but I am unable to find the "intent URL" for other apps present on the Play Store.**

**Any Help on how to find the intent URL for other apps on Play Store would be appreciated**.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Deep Learning</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <p id="case"></p>
      <button onclick="openApp()">Open App</button>
    </div>
    <script>
      var isMobile = /iPhone|iPad|iPod|Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
      (function () {
        if (isMobile) {
          document.getElementById("case").textContent =
            "I am using Mobile browser";
        } else {
          document.getElementById("case").textContent =
            "I am using Desktop/Web browser";
        }
      })();
      function openApp() {
        if (isMobile) {
          const url =
            "intent://instagram.com/#Intent;scheme=https;package=com.instagram.android;end";

          window.location.replace(url);
        } else {
          window.location.replace("https://www.instagram.com");
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: not opening app in android mobile browser

Answer (score 0):

What you trying to do is called `deeplinking`, you can achieve that by accessing `URI protocol` which is owned by your android application
For example:

`example://www.myapp.com/anystring`

**To set your app available for URI opens.
Add this receiver to your android manifest:**

```
<receiver android:name=".DeepLinkReceiver">
    <intent-filter >
        <data android:scheme="example" android:host="www.myapp.com" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**In browser side just call this method:**

```
window.open('example://www.myapp.com/anystring');
```

It will open window containing this string as url, so browser will automatically ask user to be redirected to your app

Comment: Thanks for the help, is there any pure javaScript solution for this ??

Comment: Well besides deeplinking from browser I don't know any other ways, only you can without it if you trying launch application from other android application but not from browser.

Comment: Thanks for your time and help !! I will update this post once I get the desired solution / lead.

Comment: Btw is app in which you target redirection will be made by you or it can be third party app?

Comment: any app would work. All I need to know is how to do it.

Comment: check my javaScript solution I just posted, all I need to know now is how to get intent uri as I have used it for instagram app in my solution

Comment: Yes ofcourse its working with instagram, because it is deeplinked already, but for apps which don't have deeplinking it won't work

Comment: Okay so when I deep link my app, I will get the URI just like I got for Instagram, right ? @Hex24

Comment: Yes, to make any android application deeplinked, you need add corresponding lines which are in my post to that application "AndroidManifest.xml" file. Then you call that URI string which you declared in manifest